# Connecting to a remote postgresql database from another host

Tags: postgresql, windows-10, hostname

I believe the issue is because I can't find the proper IP for hostname, but let's go for the full scenario:

`Postgresql version 9.6.1`

I already altered `pg_hba.conf` and added:

`host    all    all   0.0.0.0/0    md5`

And my `postgresql.conf` already had the input `listen_addresses = '*'`.

Also, already allowed the port `5432` through my firewall.

What I'm trying to do: set a simple PSQL **database on my PC** and connect with my Android Phone using the app `SQL Client`.
When my phone is on the same network (read WiFi) as my PC, I was able to connect just fine setting the `hostname as 192.168.XX.YY` as `IPCONFIG`told me **my PC's IP**

**What I need:** To be able to connect to the DB when my phone isn't on the same WiFi, because I won't even be in the same city as my PC will be.
The issue is that I'm not sure what IP I should add on the hostname. Tried my public IP address (by googling `what is my ip address`) and even both DNS Ip's i got from `IPCONFIG /all`.

I'm not sure how to figure out the `IP from my PC's HOSTNAME` as when I pinged it it said the physical address (something like "fa81::f7f9...") and not an IP.

**What do I have to do?** Figure a different IP? Allow something on my router? Something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that *is* and IP address, it is just IPv6 and not IPv4.

Comment: Welp, I've tried all the IP's shown on my ipconfig /all and none worked :/

Comment: Maybe a different network. Try the adress that looks like `fa81::f7f9...`.

Comment: Did, no donut..

Comment: Try to find an expert for your telephone, maybe your service provider. Maybe edit the question to include some meaningful tags. Maybe that way you can find out how to reach the PC via TCP. Once you can do that, your problem will probably be solved. So it is not really a database problem.

Comment: It's not a phone thing b/c I also could not reach it with a notebook at another network...